# WCF Metadata broken without change

Tags: c#, wcf

I am sorry if I sound agressiv but I am close to throwing my machine out of the window because this is the 3rd day in a row WCF burns my worktime.

I have created a simple WCF Service this morning. I could start it from Visual Studio so it got hosted in the WCF Service Host, I could include it as a Service Reference while running in 3 different projects. I could host in from a console application and clients can connect to it.

Now I need the Servicereference in yet another project but i cant host the wcf in the WCF Service host any more. It tells me:

> Microsoft WCF-Diensthost
>
> Der WCF-Diensthost kann keine Dienstmetadaten finden. Dies kann zu nicht ordnungsgemäßer > Ausführung der Clientanwendung führen. Überprüfen Sie, ob Metadaten aktiviert sind.
>   Möchten Sie den Vorgang beenden?
>
> Ja   Nein

Google Translation:

> Microsoft WCF Service Host
>
> The WCF Service Host can not find any service metadata. This can lead to incorrect 
>   execution of the client application. Check if metadata is enabled. Do you want to exit?
>
> Yes No

There has been no change to the WCF implementation its interface or its config. I can still host it in the console app, but I cant not get a service reference any more.
Config is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- Bei der Bereitstellung des Dienstbibliothekprojekts muss der Inhalt der Konfigurationsdatei der app.config-Datei 
  des Hosts hinzugefügt werden. System.Configuration unterstützt keine Konfigurationsdateien für Bibliotheken. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfHost.Service1Behavior" name="WcfHost.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="WcfHost.IWcfInfoHost">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8732/InfoHost/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfHost.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

How can this BEAK WITHOUT CHANGE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After recreating I figured it out. I was wrong the project was not unchanged. I changed the classname of the Interface implementation so

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="WcfHost.Service1Behavior" name="WcfHost.Service1">
```

was not correct any more.

But is is very disturbing the VS refactoring tool is unable to change the app.conf and it is most disturbing that the errormassage has nothing to do with the actual error. WCF makes me cry.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the serviceMetaData section in your web.config file:-
**serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"**

```
     <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfHost.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
```

Just set **serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled = "true"**

Please refer to https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1298.exposing-a-metadata-exchange-mex-endpoint-over-tcp-with-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service.aspx
This will fix your issue.

Comment: I have to switch on HTTP for a TCP connection?

Comment: This has nothing to do with IIS. Pleas see my answer.